# Why does phpmyadmin require a kernel update...?

Tags: apt, upgrade, phpmyadmin

I have a stable server (Ubuntu) that I want to upgrade phpmyadmin on, from 3.x to 4.x.

When I run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade phpmyadmin
```

I get:

```
root@disorient:~# apt-get upgrade phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty linux-image-generic-lts-trusty ubuntu-minimal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common apparmor apport apport-gtk apt apt-transport-https
  apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon avahi-utils bash bind9-host binutils ca-certificates coreutils
  cpio cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-filters cups-ppdc dbus dbus-x11 dnsmasq-base dnsutils dosfstools dpkg dpkg-dev
  e2fslibs e2fsprogs eject eog evince evince-common evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common file firefox
  firefox-locale-en fontconfig fonts-opensymbol foomatic-filters fuse ghostscript ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnupg gpgv grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-gconf
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-x
  gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs hplip hplip-data icedtea-6-jre-cacao
  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common jockey-common jockey-gtk krb5-locales landscape-client-ui-install
  libapache2-mod-php5 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libarchive12 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3
  libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libbind9-80 libc-ares2 libcamel-1.2-29 libcomerr2 libcups2 libcupscgi1
  libcupsdriver1 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl3-nss libdbd-mysql-perl
  libdns81 libdpkg-perl libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libebackend-1.2-1 libebook-1.2-12
  libecal-1.2-10 libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserver-1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1
  libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-trusty libegl1-mesa-lts-trusty libelf1 libevince3-3 libflac8 libfuse2 libgail-3-0 libgail-common
  libgail18 libgbm1-lts-trusty libgcrypt11 libgd2-xpm libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty
  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty libgnutls26 libgs9 libgs9-common libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common
  libgudev-1.0-0 libhpmud0 libicu48 libidn11 libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82 libjasper1 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  libldap-2.4-2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libllvm3.4 liblwres80 libmagic1 libminiupnpc8 libmysqlclient18 libnettle4 libnm-gtk-common
  libnm-gtk0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-1d libopenvg1-mesa-lts-trusty libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g
  libpcre3 libpcsclite1 libperl5.14 libpixman-1-0 libpng12-0 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler19 libpython2.7 libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml
  libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
  libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-human
  libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librrd4 libsane-hpaio libsdl1.2debian libslp1 libsmbclient libsndfile1 libsnmp-base
  libsnmp15 libsqlite3-0 libss2 libssh-4 libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-3 libtiff4 libudev0 libvncserver0 libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-trusty
  libwayland-ltst-client0 libwayland-ltst-server0 libwbclient0 libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libx11-data libx11-doc libx11-xcb1
  libxatracker2-lts-trusty libxfont1 libxi6 libxml2 libxp6 libxpm4 libxslt1.1 libxv1 lightdm linux-firmware
  linux-generic-lts-trusty linux-libc-dev makedev man-db mime-support mountall multiarch-support mysql-client-5.5
  mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 network-manager-gnome ntpdate
  openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openssh-client openssh-server openssl patch perl perl-base
  perl-modules php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql poppler-utils ppp printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs procps
  psmisc python-apport python-apt python-apt-common python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.pkcompat
  python-imaging python-lazr.restfulclient python-libxml2 python-problem-report python-uno python2.7 python2.7-minimal qdbus
  rsync rsyslog samba-common samba-common-bin smbclient ssh-askpass-gnome sudo tar tcpdump tzdata tzdata-java ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-standard udev unattended-upgrades unity-greeter uno-libs3 unzip update-manager update-manager-core upstart ure
  usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk vim-common vim-tiny wget whoopsie wpasupplicant x11-utils x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-input-dev xserver-common xserver-common-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-trusty
340 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 424 MB of archives.
After this operation, 25.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? no, for the love of god...
```

There's no way phpmyadmin requires a Firefox, cups, udev, gstreamer, gtk, linux kernel, etc. upgrade.

What is going on here and how do I make this behave sanely? I'm not prepared to update all of those things at this time, and also I'd *prefer* to use the package manager and not have a manual phpmyadmin installation.

Comment: Not a specialist of apt-get, but I was under the impression that you couldn’t `apt-get upgrade` a specific package.

Comment: @fredtantini Ohhhh, good call, looking into that now. I did check `apt-get help upgrade` for that before I posted this and it didn't seem to imply that that's not possible, but looking at it again in that light I think it might not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get upgrade
```

instructs `apt-get` to upgrade everything it can without removing any package. To upgrade a specific package, you need to `install` it:

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Ah that's it. I did check the docs for `upgrade` first but I misunderstood them. And... dang, newest version isn't in apt. Manual install it is, anyways.

Comment: Oh good, there's a repo for it, if anybody is curious: https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin